# Выделить все пробелы, кроме тех, что вокруг ключевых слов

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка

> "str str or str"

Нужно разделить по всем пробелам, но не трогать те, которые вокруг "or" в данном случае. Попробовала что-то такое `/\s+((?!or))/`, но удаётся проигнорировать пробел только перед "or".

В результате должно получиться что-то такое - `["str","str or str"]`.

Comment: (?<!or)\s(?!or)

Comment: А какая собственно задача? что-то мне подсказывает, что есть решения попроще

Comment: @MaksimTikhonov, куда уж проще регулярки в десяток символов? Наоборот, правильное решение сложнее.

Comment: @grime  спасибо! То, что нужно!

Comment: @MaksimTikhonov считать, будто пробелы между строками - это "and". Это что-то типа поискового запроса, который нужно распарсить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно найти совадения последовательности пробельных символов + `or` + пробельных символов или символов, отличных от пробельных символов:

```js
console.log(
  "str str or str".match(/(?:\s*\bor\b\s*|\S)+/gi)
);
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/57LG8w/1)

Если пробельных символов вокруг `or` должно быть 1 и более, используйте `/(?:\s+or\s+|\S)+/gi`.

**Подробности**

- `(?:` - начало незахватывающей подмаски:

  - `\s*\bor\b\s*`:

    - `\s*` - 0+ пробельных символов,
    - `\b` - граница слова
    - `or` - `or`
    - `\b` - граница слова
    - `\s*` - 0+ пробельных символов,
  - `|` - или
  - `\S`  - непробельный символ
- `)+` - конец подмаски, 1 и более повторов.

Решения для `.split()` можно использовать в средах, совместимых с ECMAScript 2018+:

```js
console.log(
   "str   str  or   str".split(/(?<!\bor\s*)\s+(?!\s*or\b)/)
)
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/N4pqxD/1/)

Тут блок предварительного просмотра назад `(?<!\bor\s*)` находит позицию в строке, сразу перед которой нет целого слова `or`, после которого может быть 0 и более пробельных символов, `\s+` находит 1 и более пробельных символов, а блок предварительного просмотра вперёд `(?!\s*or\b)` находит позицию в строке, сразу после которой нет 0 и более пробельных символов, за которыми следует целое слово `or`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log("str str or str".match(/(\s+or\s+|\S)+/gi));
```

Но вообще так себе идея так что-то парсить. Как только понадобятся скобки, этот способ принципиально перестанет работать.

Comment: может это поисковый запрос, а не логическое выражение. там скобки не шибко актуальны. не ясно правда, зачем пробелы тогда удалять вообще

Comment: @teran это действительно поисковый запрос. Там пробел считается как and

Comment: Это моё решение. См. *Если пробельных символов вокруг or должно быть 1 и более, используйте `/(?:\s+or\s+|\S)+/gi`*

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, ага, не заметил.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, ну лишь бы минус поставить :( Я-то тебе плюсанул...